# Aggregated timestamp with 1 second difference in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have pyspark data frame like below sample (original data has 1.5 records per day). It contains user data, containing start time and end time columns and several demographic variables (id, age_group, county etc). Many records have only 1 second time difference

```
+--------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
|id      | date        | group   |start_time             | end_time          | duration|
+--------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
|    78aa| 2020-04-14  | 3       |    2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|24       |
|    78aa| 2020-04-14  | 3       |    2020-04-14 19:24:00|2020-04-14 19:26:59|4        |
|    78aa| 2020-04-14  | 3       |    2020-04-14 19:27:00|2020-04-14 19:35:59|8        |
|    78aa| 2020-04-14  | 3       |    2020-04-14 19:36:00|2020-04-14 19:55:00|19       |
|    25aa| 2020-04-15  | 7       |    2020-04-15 08:00:00|2020-04-15 08:02:59|3        |
|    25aa| 2020-04-15  | 7       |    2020-04-15 11:03:00|2020-04-15 11:11:59|9        |
|    25aa| 2020-04-15  | 7       |    2020-04-15 11:12:00|2020-04-15 11:45:59|34       |
|    25aa| 2020-04-15  | 7       |    2020-04-15 11:46:00|2020-04-15 11:47:00|1        |
+--------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

My attempt: for entire day aggregation data

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, first

df = df.groupBy("date" , "id" ).agg(first("group"), sum("duration"))\
.toDF("data","id","group", "duration")
```

I need also to transfer dataframe at user aggregate level during the day. How do I obtain this with pyspark? I don't want to convert my data into pandas dataframe since pandas will load data into the driver's memory and I will face memory issue: here is desired output

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
|id      |  date        |group |start_time             | end_time          | duration|
+--------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
|    78aa|  2020-04-14  | 3    |    2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:55:00|55       |
|    25aa|  2020-04-15  | 7    |    2020-04-15 08:00:00|2020-04-15 08:02:59|3        |
|    25aa|  2020-04-15  | 7    |    2020-04-15 11:00:00|2020-04-15 11:47:00|44       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Need to create an **`additional column`** to *`group the timings`* where they **`succeed each other by 1 second`** using *window functions.*

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("id","date","group").orderBy("start_time")
df.withColumn("check", F.sum(F.when(F.unix_timestamp("start_time")-F.lag(F.unix_timestamp("end_time")).over(w)>1,F.lit(1))\
                        .otherwise(F.lit(0))).over(w))\
  .groupBy("date","id","group","check").agg(F.first("start_time").alias("start_time"),F.last("end_time").alias("end_time"),\
                                   F.sum("duration").alias("duration")).drop("check").show()

#+----------+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|      date|  id|group|         start_time|           end_time|duration|
#+----------+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|2020-04-14|78aa|    3|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:55:00|      55|
#|2020-04-15|25aa|    7|2020-04-15 08:00:00|2020-04-15 08:02:59|       3|
#|2020-04-15|25aa|    7|2020-04-15 11:03:00|2020-04-15 11:47:00|      44|
#+----------+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val df0 = Seq(
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", 3, "2020-04-14 19:00:00", "2020-04-14 19:23:59", 24),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", 3, "2020-04-14 19:24:00", "2020-04-14 19:26:59", 4),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", 3, "2020-04-14 19:27:00", "2020-04-14 19:35:59", 8),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", 3, "2020-04-14 19:36:00", "2020-04-14 19:55:00", 19),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", 7, "2020-04-15 08:00:00", "2020-04-15 08:02:59", 3),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", 7, "2020-04-15 11:03:00", "2020-04-15 11:11:59", 9),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", 7, "2020-04-15 11:12:00", "2020-04-15 11:45:59", 34),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", 7, "2020-04-15 11:46:00", "2020-04-15 11:47:00", 1)
    ).toDF("id", "date", "group", "start_time", "end_time", "duration")

    val df1 = df0.withColumn("start_time_1", date_format('start_time, "YYYY-MM-dd HH"))

    df1.show(false)

    val res = df1.groupBy("id", "date", "group", "start_time_1")
      .agg(min('start_time).alias("start_time"), max('end_time).alias("end_time"), sum('duration).alias("duration"))
      .orderBy('start_time.asc)
      .drop("start_time_1")

    res.show(false)
//    +----+----------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
//    |id  |date      |group|start_time         |end_time           |duration|
//    +----+----------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
//    |78aa|2020-04-14|3    |2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:55:00|55      |
//    |25aa|2020-04-15|7    |2020-04-15 08:00:00|2020-04-15 08:02:59|3       |
//    |25aa|2020-04-15|7    |2020-04-15 11:03:00|2020-04-15 11:47:00|44      |
//    +----+----------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```